# How to disable certain Apps & access to PIM data on iOS

Tags: ipad, ios, applications, security, privacy

Anybody can describe how to disable certain apps on iOS and disable access to PIM (calendar, contacts, reminders, email) data? I've looked at the Restrictions feature and find that it limits access to apps by rating instead of disabling particular apps.

The reason being is that I'm prepping up for a trade show and will be handing over my personal iPad to a colleague (we're a tiny business) for use as an interactive display in the show. I'm OK if he use it to browse the web or even play some games, but I don't want him to go around looking at my e-mail, calendar, and financial records (hence, disabling PIM and some apps that owns critical data).

This event will last a couple of days and thus erasing my iPad just for this is a bit too much – I've had missing apps the last time I had to erase and restore due to an OS upgrade. Not to mention that we need some specific apps and data to be loaded on the device for use in the event (that is, a blank iPad won't be sufficient).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, under stock iOS there is no way to restrict apps except thru the parental controls you already mentioned.

Outside of the stock iOS however, there are multiple solutions to do this, my favourite of which is iUsers that enables multiple user accounts including guest accounts on iOS devices.